# How to get distinct count of values of all the columns of a table based on where condition in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with records which has 100 columns, I need to get the count of distinct values of all the columns from this table based on some condition (where clause).

Below query is working fine, but I'm not able to use the where clause. So it's giving the result for all the records of the table. But I want it to be based on some condition lets say column file_id = 1;. My question is how to use where clause with the below query. Or if there is any other alternative way to solve this problem.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = ''
;with cols as (
select Table_Schema, Table_Name, Column_Name, Row_Number() over(partition by Table_Schema, Table_Name
order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as RowNum
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
)

select @SQL = @SQL + case when RowNum = 1 then '' else ' union all ' end
+ ' select ''' + Column_Name + ''' as Column_Name, count(distinct ' + quotename (Column_Name) + ' ) As DistinctCountValue, 
count( '+ quotename (Column_Name) + ') as CountValue FROM ' + quotename (Table_Schema) + '.' + quotename (Table_Name)
from cols
where Table_Name = 'table_name' --print @SQL

execute (@SQL)
```

I am using the dynamic query because I need to reuse this query for other tables also.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by _get distinct count of all the columns of a table_ does your table has duplicate columns??? No way. 2) Why even you need a Dynamic SQL for this?

Comment: Sorry, it’s distinct count of values of all the columns

Comment: @Sami I am using the dynamic query because I need to reuse this query for other tables also.

Comment: @viveknuna can you show u an example of an expected output ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get the columns and use stuff to generate the select in this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(ColumnA) AS ColumnA, COUNT(ColumnB AS ColumnB), COUNT(ColumnC) AS ColumnC....
```

That way you only select on your table once to get all counts, After that, use `CROSS APPLY` to "unpivot" those columns and return the output on one row per column

```
CROSS APPLY(
    VALUES(1, 'ColumnA', ColumnA), (2, 'ColumnB', ColumnB), (3, 'ColumnC', ColumnC)
)(ID, ColumnName, DistinctCountValue)
```

For the filter, use sp_executesql and send the file_id as parameter

```
exec SP_executesql @SQL, N'@FID INT', @FID = @FileID
```

Since you are using all columns of the table `Row_Number() over(partition by Table_Schema, Table_Name order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as RowNum` becomes redundant, ORDINAL_POSITION already has the value that you are looking for

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(50) = 'MyTestTable'
declare @fileID int = 1
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = ''
;with cols as (
select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
)

select @SQL = ';WITH  CTE AS (SELECT 
' + 
    STUFF((
    SELECT ', COUNT(DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
    FROM cols
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
+ '
FROM ' + @TableName + '
WHERE File_ID = @FID
)
SELECT B.*
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ' +STUFF((
    SELECT ',( ' + CAST(ORDINAL_POSITION AS VARCHAR) + ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'''') + ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ')'
    FROM cols
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') + '
)B (ID,ColumnName,DistinctCountValue) 
'
from cols


exec SP_executesql @SQL, N'@FID INT', @FID = @FileID
```

Answer (score 4):

The query below creates a table of all the column names and uses a while loop to select the count for whatever WHERE clause you want to use. This should be pretty flexible for any table; just update the top variables. Note that this will not count a column where its value is null. You can add a case to the @Query parameter if that's what you want. Since it processes each row individually, I added in a temp table so you only hit the db once.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##SourceValues') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##SourceValues
DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(50) = 'SomeSchema'
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(50) = 'SomeTable'
DECLARE @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX) = ' Some WHERE clause'
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ProcessedRows TABLE(ColumnName VARCHAR(50), DistinctCount INT)
DECLARE @Columns TABLE(RowNumber INT,  ColumnName VARCHAR(100)) 
INSERT INTO @Columns SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC),  COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT MAX(RowNumber) FROM @Columns)
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @DistinctCount INT 
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
EXEC('SELECT * INTO ##SourceValues FROM ' + @Table +' (NOLOCK)')
WHILE @Counter < @Count
BEGIN 
    SET @Counter += 1
    SET @ColumnName = (SELECT ColumnName FROM @Columns WHERE RowNumber = @Counter)
    SET @Query = 'SELECT @OutPut = COUNT(' + @ColumnName + ') FROM ' + @Schema + '.' + ' ##SourceValues ' + @WhereClause
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, N'@Output INT OUT', @DistinctCount OUT
    INSERT INTO @ProcessedRows(ColumnName, DistinctCount) VALUES (@ColumnName, @DistinctCount)
END
SELECT * FROM @ProcessedRows
```

Answer (score 4):

**Let's try some different approach.**

Get all values unpivoted as Param/Value:

**1) Collect list of tables and columns to be used in dynamic SQL:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Base;
;WITH SchemaData AS (
    SELECT t.name AS [TableName],c.name AS [ColumnName],c.column_id AS [ColumnOrderID]
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
)
SELECT t.TableName
    ,STUFF((SELECT ',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),' + QUOTENAME([ColumnName]) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME([ColumnName]) 
            FROM SchemaData a WHERE (a.TableName = t.TableName) FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [SelectClause]
    ,STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([ColumnName]) FROM SchemaData a WHERE (a.TableName = t.TableName) FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [UnpivotClause]
INTO #Base
FROM SchemaData t
GROUP BY t.TableName
;
```

**2) Get all data inside a temp table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Result;
CREATE TABLE #Result(TableName NVARCHAR(255),ColumnName NVARCHAR(255),[Value] NVARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255),@SelectClause NVARCHAR(MAX),@UnpivotClause NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE crPopulateResult CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR SELECT b.TableName,b.SelectClause,b.UnpivotClause FROM #Base b;

OPEN crPopulateResult;
FETCH NEXT FROM crPopulateResult INTO @TableName,@SelectClause,@UnpivotClause;

DECLARE @dSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @dSql = N'   INSERT INTO #Result(TableName,[ColumnName],[Value])
    SELECT up.TableName,up.Param AS [ColumnName],up.[Value]
    FROM (
        SELECT ''' + @TableName + N''' AS [TableName]
            ,' + @SelectClause + N'
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'
    ) a
    UNPIVOT(Value FOR Param IN (' + @UnpivotClause + N')) up
    ';
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @dSql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM crPopulateResult INTO @TableName,@SelectClause,@UnpivotClause;
END

CLOSE crPopulateResult;
DEALLOCATE crPopulateResult;
```

**3) Any filters can be applied with #Results, including Table names, column names, data filters, etc:**

```
SELECT r.TableName,r.ColumnName,COUNT(*) AS [CountValue],COUNT(DISTINCT r.[Value]) AS [DistinctCountValue]
FROM #Result r
--
--WHERE r.ColumnName = 'file_id' AND r.[Value] = '1'
--
GROUP BY r.TableName,r.ColumnName
ORDER BY r.TableName,r.ColumnName
;
```

Answer (score 2):

To use this with a where clause with this query you just have to put the where clause in the construction after the table name so if you wanted to filter on file_id='1' then you would have:

```
FROM ' + quotename (Table_Schema) + '.' + quotename (Table_Name) +'where file_id =''1'' '
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `@where` variable and concatenate that with your big union construction (as part of your `select ... from cols`).  For example:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @where nvarchar(max) = ' where file_id = 1'

set @SQL = ''
;with cols as (
select Table_Schema, Table_Name, Column_Name, Row_Number() over(partition by Table_Schema, Table_Name
order by ORDINAL_POSITION) as RowNum
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
)
select @SQL = @SQL + case when RowNum = 1 then '' else ' union all ' end
+ ' select ''' + Column_Name + ''' as Column_Name, count(distinct ' + quotename (Column_Name) + ' ) As DistinctCountValue, 
count( '+ quotename (Column_Name) + ') as CountValue FROM ' + quotename (Table_Schema) + '.' + quotename (Table_Name)
+ @where
from cols
where Table_Name = 'table_name' --print @SQL

execute (@SQL)
```

Note that you'll need to escape single quotes in `@where` if you're searching for a string.  For example, `declare @where nvarchar(max) = ' where state = ''CT'''`.